# how to change exact path after successful login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6, jsx

i am making a login page that redirect the user after a successful login to home page i am using react router dom i tried to look for a simple way to do it but i couldn't find :

```
import Authen from './Pages/Authen';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
  <div className="App"> 

    <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
      </ul>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Authen}/>
      <Route path="Home" component={Home}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
  </div>
```

thank you for your help i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> login page that redirect the user after a successful login to home
>   page

Use the `withRouter` higher order component that comes with react-router-dom. It will give your component acess to the history prop. With the history prop you can push to any new URL.

```
import React from 'react'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

class Authen extends React.Component {

onLogin = () => {
  // also other authentication code
 this.props.history.push('/home')
}

render() {
 return (
   <button onClick={() => this.onLogin()}> Login </button>
  )   
 }   
}

export default withRouter(Authen);
```